# Proof: if $R$ is symmetric then so is $R^{-1}$

Tags: logic, proof-verification, relations, predicate-logic

This is one problem I have been solving in Velleman's `How to prove` book:

> Suppose $R$ is a relation on $A$, prove that if $R$ is symmetric, then
>   so is $R^{-1}$.

Now this is my proof:

> Suppose $R$ is symmetric. Let $a$ and $b$ be an arbitrary element in
>   $A$ such that $(a,b) \in R^{-1}$. From $(a,b) \in R^{-1}$ it follows
>   that $(b,a) \in R$. Since $R$ is symmetric, it follows that $(a,b) \in
>  R$. So, $(b,a) \in R^{-1}$. Therefore, if $(a,b) \in R^{-1}$ then
>   $(b,a) \in  R^{-1}$. Since $a$  and $b$ are arbitrary, it follows that
>   $R^{-1}$ is  symmetric

.

I have been verifying my proof from [here](http://technotes-himanshu.blogspot.in/2010/05/how-to-prove-it-ch4-sec43more-about.html) and they have given a slightly different proof:

> Suppose R is symmetric. Let x,y be arbitrary elements of A s.t.
>   (x,y)∈R. It follows from our assumption that (y,x)∈R also. Then $(x,y) \in R^{-1}$ and $(y,x) \in R^{-1}$ as well. Since x, y are arbitrary,
>    so If R is symmetric then so is $R^{-1}$.

In the above proof they are staring from the assumption that $(x,y) \in R$ which I think is not correct. Am I missing something here?

Comment: The "Therefore $(a,b)\in R^{-1}% line seems wrong. That was your assumption, no need to deduce it.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks, updated that part.

Comment: What does the ">" symbol mean in $(x,y)>\in R^{-1}$ and $(a,b)\in>R$ mean?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Sorry, it's an formatting error. Fixed that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both your proof and the one you quote are correct. There's no reason why we couldn't start with $(x,y)\in R$.

However, the proof could be made clearer by saying:
$$(x,y)\in R\Longrightarrow (y,x)\in R^{-1}\quad\text{(definition)}$$
$$(x,y)\in R\Longrightarrow (y,x)\in R\quad\text{(symmetry)}$$
$$(y,x)\in R\Longrightarrow (x,y)\in R^{-1}\quad\text{(definition)}$$

instead of:

> It follows from our assumption that $(y,x)\in R$ also. Then $(x,y)\in R^{-1}$ and $(y,x)\in R^{-1}$ as well.

That way you see exactly where everything is coming from - but that's just my personal opinion.